# Load more data on page scroll Using php, Data source JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

i developed a deal and coupon site and my data source is JSON. and my json file is big around 4MB. i want to show first 30 data and after scroll load next 30. so please tell me how can i do this work using JSON.
here is my code:

```
<?php $json = file_get_contents('offers.json');
$json_decode = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($json_decode as $data){
?>
<div class="ad-box">
<div class="ad-category"><?php echo $data['category'];?></div>
<div class="ad-image"><img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $data['imageUrl'];?>" src="" width="150" height="140" border="0" alt="lazy Image"/></div>
<div class="ad-title"><a href="<?php echo $data['url'];?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $data['title'] . " : " . $data['description'];?></a></div>
<div class="ad-url"><a href="<?php echo $data['url'];?>" target="_blank">Goto Offer</a></div>

</div>
<?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

your Json array is unknow but:

Main page:

```
<div id="loadbox">

    <?php
    $json = file_get_contents('offers.json');
    $json_decode = json_decode($json, true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 29; $i++):
        $data = $json_decode[$i];
        ?>
        <div class="ad-box">
            <div class="ad-category"><?php echo $data['category']; ?></div>
            <div class="ad-image"><img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $data['imageUrl']; ?>" src="" width="150" height="140" border="0" alt="lazy Image"/></div>
            <div class="ad-title"><a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $data['title'] . " : " . $data['description']; ?></a></div>
            <div class="ad-url"><a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" target="_blank">Goto Offer</a></div>

        </div>
        <?php
    endfor;
    ?>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var last = 30;

    function getData(lst) {
        $.get("loader.php", {'last': lst}, function (data) {
            $("#loadbox").append(data);
            last += 30 ;
        });
    }
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            buffer = 40 // # of pixels from bottom of scroll to fire your function. Can be 0
            if ($("html").prop('scrollHeight') - $("html").scrollTop() <= $("html").height() + buffer) {
                getDate(last);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

in the main page you load first 30 records and active ajax on scroll end.

when one loader for ajax request:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('offers.json');
$json_decode = json_decode($json, true);
$start = (int) $_GET['last'] ;
for ($i = $start ; $i < ($start+30) ; $i++):
    $data = $json_decode[$i];
    ?>
    <div class="ad-box">
        <div class="ad-category"><?php echo $data['category']; ?></div>
        <div class="ad-image"><img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $data['imageUrl']; ?>" src="" width="150" height="140" border="0" alt="lazy Image"/></div>
        <div class="ad-title"><a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $data['title'] . " : " . $data['description']; ?></a></div>
        <div class="ad-url"><a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" target="_blank">Goto Offer</a></div>

    </div>
    <?php
endfor;
?>
```

Comment: sir i copy and paste Main page: block in index.php and 2nd block of code paste in loader.php and add script https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js in top of head. but on scroll not working.. plz help..

Comment: I dont know about your json structure. and need to bee change and debug.

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: getDate is not defined " this error is coming

Comment: @ShurvirMori In part one of  code: `function getData(lst) {` you can see ^

Comment: @A1Gard , Now i got it. it's your spelling mistake. you mentioned " getDate " instead of "getData" kindly update it. but obviously browser doesn't understand :D LoL. don't mind  it.